# meteor npm install --production

Tags: meteor, npm

What does these lines mean
`meteor npm install --production`
`meteor npm install --save`
?
The [Docs](https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteornpm) explains the command `meteor npm <pacakge name>` So the npm package is [install](https://www.npmjs.com/package/install), but what does the flag `--production and --save` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `meteor npm` command simply forwards the arguments that follow it to Meteor's bundled `npm` version, so it behaves as the npm command-line tool.

- The **basic command** is `meteor npm <command and arguments`.
- This **basic install** command is `meteor npm install <package name>` rather than `meteor npm <package name>`.

Its relevant documentation is therefore not the one you referenced in your question, but the [npm's CLI](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) tool's (you referenced npm's `install` package, note the `npm install install` there).

NPM creates a `package.json` file and lists the project's dependencies there. You use the `--save` flag to instruct npm to add the packages installed to the dependencies file and the `--production` flag to instruct npm to not install its `dev-dependencies`, which are dependencies that were used for developing and debugging this package, but are not strictly required for its operation in production.

Take the time to familiarize yourself with the tool.

---

From the CLI docs:

```
npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>

alias: npm i
common options: [-S|--save|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional] [-E|--save-exact] [--dry-run]
```

> -S, --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.
>
> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.